# xs:String in xs:DateTime format to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I use JAXB for un/marshaling XML messages which I get from server. Usually I get the XMLGregorianCalendar values in the fields, that are defind as xs:dateTime in the describing XSD files, so the conversion to XMLGregorianCalendar is done automatically by JAXB.

Example from XSD file

```
<xs:attribute name="readouttime" use="required" type="xs:dateTime" />
```

However one field is defined as xs:string like this:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" type="xs:string" />
```

but I am receiving a value that should represent the dateTime:

```
<Value>2014-08-31T15:00:00Z</Value>
```

Is there any nice way, how to convert this string to XMLGregorianCallendar, or should I use SimpleDateFormat and type the pattern manually? I feel this may be a dangerous part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick Google search yields

```
String mydatetime = "2011-09-29T08:55:00";
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(mydatetime);
```

Credits go to [this blog post](http://larryjjcao.blogspot.de/2012/04/how-to-convert-string-to.html).

Answer (score 2):

My idea

```
String time = "yourTimeStamp"; 
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yourFormat"); 
Date myDate = f.parse(time); 
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(myDate); 
XMLGregorianCalendar myDate2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on your field like this..

```
@XmlElement(name = "string", required = true) 
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
protected XMLGregorianCalendar value;
```

DateAdapter.java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, XMLGregorianCalendar> {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    public String marshal(XMLGregorianCalendar v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

    public XMLGregorianCalendar unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(v);
    }

}
```

Comment: I got a NullPointerException 

com.sun.xml.bind.api.AccessorException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:247)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:262)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeAttributes(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:390)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:689)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158

Comment: @AyadiAkrem it would be better have a case scenario to evaluate xml, pojo, etc

Comment: that is what I did